# How to handle with Httperror 303 in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, redirect, urllib2

When I run the following code:

```
url = 'http://www.nytimes.com/2011/11/15/arts/music/new-music-from-caveman-los-campesinos-and-the-fall.html?_r=0'
try:
    handle = urllib2.urlopen(url).info()    
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print(e.code)
```

There is an error and `print e.code` prints `303`.
If I request this URL using Chrome or Firefox, it works fine.

Anyone can help?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to handle the redirection because [HTTP 303 is a "See Other"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) response. The location where the content is at will be given to you in the `Location` header:

```
>>> e.headers['Location']
'http://www-nc.nytimes.com/2011/11/15/arts/music/new-music-from-caveman-los-campesinos-and-the-fall.html?=_r=6&'
```

---

Now, using `urllib` / `urllib2` today is really asking for pain, what you should actually do is use the excellent [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library, which will handle everything for you.

I think we can say that using `requests` is the correct way of doing HTTP in Python:

```
>>> res = requests.get(url)
<Response [200]>
>>> print res.text
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" # And so on
```

Comment: I'd add here that urllib2 is incorrectly deciding that the redirect NYT is doing leads to a perpetual loop. You could write a custom redirect handler to teach urllib2 how to handle the results from NYT, but I think using the requests library will actually prove to be much simpler overall.

Comment: @GeoffGerrietts That's exact. It also happens that the Location to which we are redirected requires login. Oh, well, so much for `urllib`.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The request library is easy to use.

Comment: the NYT website requires cookies, otherwise you fall in a perpetual loop. urllib2 is doing nothing wrong here. `requests` is a bit an overkill just to handle cookies.

Answer (score 0):

303 is a redirect. Your browser handles it automatically, urllib2 needs some coaxing.

Check this out for a very good explanation:

http://www.diveintopython.net/http_web_services/redirects.html